# How to create the nice buttons on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I am not sure if this is a total stupid question and that I just do not see it but I just get it.

Apple has this nice shiny button used on several occasions, e.g. stop-watch

[image]

Now, how can you create those buttons ? In code and Interface Designer ?

Or is it only possible by using images for the different button states ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are numerous samples available online.

Try these ones:-

[cool-tool-for-quickly-making-glossy-ios-buttons](http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/cool-tool-for-quickly-making-glossy-ios-buttons/)

[drawing-gloss-gradients](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/drawing-gloss-gradients-in-coregraphics.html)

[Gradient Button](https://github.com/kickingvegas/YmsGradientButton)

I hope, it helps

Comment: +1 For the gimp/photoshop challenged among us, ButtonMaker is brilliant (top link)!

Comment: That ButtonMaker is not working properly any more. Has compile errors and even if you fix them there is no button preview.

Comment: Didn't work for me either using Xcode 4.3.3.  Code refers to nameField which is not in the NIB.  Fixed that but there is no button preview and when you hit the save button there's a flood of "invalid context" errors in the console.

Comment: ButtonMaker (top link) doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 3):

I use Art Text. There is a lite version that is free. You can [download Art Text from the Mac App store](http://www.belightsoft.com/products/arttext/overview.php).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mattlawer/BButton

BButton 2.0
BButton is a subclass of UIButton that looks like the Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.1 buttons.

Refactored by @jessesquires, April 2013.

Includes @leberwurstsaft / FontAwesome-for-iOS, fixed for iOS from the original FontAwesome.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use this [custom button component](http://www.binpress.com/app/glossy-button-for-ios/968).

[image]