# On iPhone / iPad, how to make Buttons with a groove without using images?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, uibutton

Some Apple apps on iPhone / iPad like to use ***UIButton with a groove around it***.

An example is:

[image]

***Note that there is a "groove" around the button***.  Is there a built in method to add them for UIButton, without using images?  If not, then what may be a good way to make it?  Right now I am thinking of adding 3 CALayer layers to the button layer, (1) one with dark gray (top) to lighter gray (bottom) gradient as the lowest level layer, (2) a black and smaller one that covers up layer 1, and (3) the color gradient layer.  Here is a bigger version of one of the buttons:

[image]

Comment: Jess Martin has a good example up on [Github](https://github.com/jessmartin/CoolButtons).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966924/how-to-create-the-nice-buttons-on-ios

Comment: the question is about the groove around the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your UIButton inside a UIView. Set the border width  and border color of the button to match the black outline.

Center the button in the view, then make the view slightly bigger than the button with a gray background.

Finally, set the:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = {the button's corner radius};
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I have not tested this, but it seems like it should work without messing with layers too much.

edit: make sure to #import < QuartzCore /QuartzCore. >